# Java updating records in derby database

Tags: java, sql, derby, joptionpane

This is the java code that I have so far, a simple app to manage employees using joptionpane,  I can get the password thing and    I can insert the records into database working no problem but I can't get it update the records, if I try to update any of the records it dose not work the records just stay the same

Can someone please help me  thanks

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class EMP {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      PreparedStatement prest;           
        int count = 0;
        String username = "";
        String password = "";


       while (count < 5 && (!(username.equals("Brian")) && (!password.equals("Student")))) {

                username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter your Username ");

                password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter your Password ");
                count++;

                if (username.equals("Brian") && password.equals("Student")) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " login successfully \n Welcome" + username );
                    break;

                }

                if (count >= 5) {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have used to many attempts \n " + "you will not be able to sing in for an hour");
                   System.exit(0);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password \n please try again  \n"+ "you have used " + count  + " out of 5 attpemts \n  before your account will be locked for 1 hour");


                }
        }

                String Option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter one of the options \n A. Add a new Employee \n B. Upate Empoyess record  \n C. Search Employee name by their id number \n D. List All employess \n E. Delete Employee\n F. Exit System \n Your Chosse   ");
            if (Option.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {

                String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess ID", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess First NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Surname NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String pss = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess PPS Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
                String cnum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please ente thr Employess Contact Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String address  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  Address", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Deparment ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  salary", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, id + sname +  "Records have been entered ");

       try{

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost/ee ";
    String uName = "aa";
    String uPass = "bb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
//Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
//Customer Lookup by Last Name

//SQL

String sql =  "INSERT INTO emp (id, fname, sname, pss, cnum,  address,  dep, sal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )";

prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);

// Variable Customer Name Passes up to SQL as ?
    prest.setString(1,id);
    prest.setString(2,fname);
        prest.setString(3,sname);
    prest.setString(4,pss);
    prest.setString(5,cnum);
    prest.setString(6,address);
        prest.setString(7,dep);
        prest.setString(8,sal);
    prest.executeUpdate();


    }
    catch (SQLException err) {

    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }



} else if (Option.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {

 String id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess ID", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess First NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Surname NAME", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String pss = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the Employess PPS Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
                String cnum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please ente thr Employess Contact Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String address  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  Address", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String dep = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess Deparment ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                String sal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter Employess  salary", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, id + sname +  "Records have been entered ");

       try{

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost/ee ";
    String uName = "aa";
    String uPass = "bb";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
//Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
//Customer Lookup by Last Name

//SQL

String sql = "UPDATE emp SET  fname = [?],sname = [?],pss = [?],cnum = [?],address = [?],dep = [?],sal =[?], where id = [?]";



prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);


    prest.setString(1,id);
    prest.setString(2,fname);
        prest.setString(3,sname);
    prest.setString(4,pss);
    prest.setString(5,cnum);
    prest.setString(6,address);
        prest.setString(7,dep);
        prest.setString(8,sal);
    prest.executeUpdate();


    }
    catch (SQLException err) {

    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
    }
                }

    }
```

Comment: It's Java, not JavaScript

Comment: you have a comma in the wrong place in the query `sal =[?], where id = [?]`.  Remove that.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the exception? Show the full details: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: @ Bryan Pendleton  When I run it I get the following Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 24. BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 44 seconds)